# Angular *ngFor on array of objects error in IE only

Tags: arrays, angular, templates, object, ngfor

I am getting the following error when using *ngFor to render an array of JSON object data.

> ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object
>   Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]' of type
>   'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

This works fine in all browser clients except IE. So unsure why IE is blowing up.

**Template:**

```
<div #portfolioSites class="frame {{siteIndex.type}}" *ngFor="let siteIndex of sites">
    <div class="app-header">
      <div class="buttons">
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
      </div>
      <div class="app-tab">
        {{siteIndex.tab}}
      </div>
      <div class="app-tab-border"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="home-button"></div>
    <img src="{{siteIndex.image}}" alt="{{siteIndex.image_alt}}" />
</div>
```

**Data:**

```
sites = [
    {
      type: 'web',
      label: 'placeholder',
      description: '',
      tab: 'placeholder',
      image: 'assets/images/portfolio/placeholder.gif',
      image_alt: 'placeholder.com',
      url: 'http://www.placeholder.com'
    },
    {
      type: 'web',
      label: 'placeholder',
      description: '',
      tab: 'placeholder',
      image: 'assets/images/portfolio/placeholder.gif',
      image_alt: 'placeholder.com',
      url: 'http://www.placeholder.com'
    },
    {
      type: 'web',
      label: 'placeholder',
      description: '',
      tab: 'placeholder',
      image: 'assets/images/portfolio/placeholder.gif',
      image_alt: 'placeholder.com',
      url: 'http://www.placeholder.com'
    }
  ];
```

Comment: The error occurs only when you use anything except array in `*ngFor` . Try to just print the `sites` in template like `{{sites}}` and see what is actually coming.

Comment: **I did the following:**

`const isArr = this.sites instanceof Array;
console.log(isArr);

console.log(Object.prototype.toString.call(this.sites));

console.log(this.sites);

console.log(typeof this.sites);`


**And these are my results:**

`true
[object Array]
[{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
object`